# React-Native Javascript Search Filter Function

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, search

I am trying to search for these ingredients in this array and add the value to the `data` to display it but it is not working. I am very new to javascript so i'd really appreciate if anyone is kind enough to  help me out .This is what I have done:

```
const Search = () => {
  const ingridients = [ ["paprika", "parsley"], ["steak", "ground beef"],["milk", "eggs", "cheese"] ]
  const [input, setInput] = useState();

  const categorize = (term) => {
    setInput(ter )
    let data = []
    if (term) {
      const newData = ingridients.filter(() => {
        if (RegExp(searchTerm, "gim").exec())
            return RegExp(searchTerm, "gim").exec()
      }) 
    } else {
      data = []
    }
  }
  return(
      <TextInput onChange={(text)=> categorize(text)} value={input}/>
  )
}
```

Comment: you 2d array of strings. why not simple array of strings? can you add a screen shot and explain what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to let user search for paprika for example and if I render `data` with Flatlist user can see search suggestions which is being rendered from the ingredients function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const ingridients = [
    'paprika',
    'parsley',
    'steak',
    'ground beef',
    'milk',
    'eggs',
    'cheese',
  ];
  const [input, setInput] = useState();
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);

  const filter = (term) => {
    setInput(term);
    if(/\d/.test(term) || /[a-zA-Z]/.test(term)) {
        setFilteredData(ingridients.filter(ingridient => ingridient.includes(term)));
    } 
    else {
       setFilteredData([]);
    }
  };
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={(text) => filter(text)}
        value={input}
        style={{ backgroundColor: 'grey' }}
      />
      <View style={{ padding: 40 }}>
        {filteredData.map(ingridient => (
          <Text style={{ color: 'black' }}>{ingridient}</Text>
        ))}
      </View>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this !!!!!! how do I edit this to only show suggestions when the user has typed? So like if there is no input it doesn't set the data even if I backspace and there's no input

Comment: You welcome. I edited the filter function so it will show values only when there is alphabet  input